# Need more details information of how to convert windows 11 to Ubuntu properly

Tags: partitioning

> I have a laptop where windows 11 installed. There is C drive [256GB
> SSD] consisting Operating system and another D drive [ 1 GB HDD ]
> consisting image, videos etc. Now I want to convert my system to
> Ubuntu LTS. I want to install ubuntu in C drive by replacing existing
> windows11 operating system. and I want to mount my D drive as /home/d
> path.

ChatGPT gave below answer of the following query. but I want to know disk partitioning and swap memory creation step with more details [probably with some relevant images] which GPT unable to provide. Can anyone help me with those steps?

**ChatGPT answer start**

To replace Windows 11 with Ubuntu LTS on your laptop and mount the D drive as /home/d, you'll need to follow these steps:

**Important: Make sure to back up any important data on your D drive before proceeding, as this process will erase all data on the C drive.**

1. **Prepare a Bootable Ubuntu USB Drive:**
   a. Download the Ubuntu LTS ISO file from the official website.
   b. Create a bootable USB drive using tools like Rufus (on Windows) or balenaEtcher (on Linux).
   c. Insert the bootable USB drive into your laptop.
2. **Access the BIOS/UEFI:**
   a. Turn off your laptop.
   b. Turn it back on and repeatedly press the key (usually F2, F12, Delete, or Esc) to access the BIOS/UEFI settings.
   c. In the BIOS/UEFI settings, set the boot order to prioritize booting from the USB drive.
3. **Install Ubuntu:**
   a. Boot your laptop from the Ubuntu USB drive.
   b. Select "Install Ubuntu" from the boot menu.
   c. Follow the on-screen instructions.
   d. When you reach the "Installation type" screen, select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu." This will erase the C drive and install Ubuntu on it.
4. **Mount the D Drive as /home/d:**
   a. After the installation is complete, boot into your new Ubuntu installation.
   b. Open a terminal (you can search for "Terminal" in the applications).
   c. Use the following commands to find the UUID of your D drive and create a mount point for it:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   Note the UUID of your D drive (the HDD).
   d. Create a mount point for your D drive:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/d
   ```

   e. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file to mount your D drive at /home/d on boot. Use a text editor like Nano or Vim to open the file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```

   Add the following line to the file, replacing `<UUID>` with the UUID of your D drive:

   ```
   UUID=<UUID> /home/d ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```

   f. Save the file and exit the text editor.
5. **Reboot:**
   a. Reboot your laptop:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Your Ubuntu LTS installation should now use the D drive as /home/d, effectively replacing Windows 11 on the C drive with Ubuntu while keeping your data on the D drive intact.

Remember to back up any important data before proceeding, and be cautious when working with disk partitions and the `/etc/fstab` file, as incorrect changes can cause data loss or system issues.

**ChatGPT answer ends**

Comment: Why don't you follow the official instructions instead of a mindless AI???

Comment: which one you are talking about? please give the link it would be helpful. actually everywhere I'm seeing people either talking about dual boot or WSL

Comment: You can either dual-boot, or you can erase the entire disk and only install Ubuntu. See here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation

Comment: The detail that most interests me as what *file-systems* exist on what you want to re-use.  Usually microsoft windows prefers its own format (eg. NTFS) but can also use some legacy formats (fat32 etc), but those are not native for a Ubuntu/Linux system; thus I'd not use it for `/home` (I'd not want those costs!)  I'd keep a NTFS file-system if I had to, but I'd suggest mounting it other than `/home` so all file metadata can be saved correctly.

Comment: Ignore all that AI generated garbage. Although I did find its "important" warning hilarious: back up D:, because this procedure destroys C:. LOL

Answer (score 0):

> another D drive [ 1 GB HDD ] consisting image, videos etc.

1. Copy date from disks C and D to any Cloud (Google disk) and back up it additionally to external SSD
2. Load Ubuntu from Live CD
3. Check that you can use the data from cloud and you don't lose anything.
4. Install Ubuntu by removing all data and OS from two drives.